# :host ::ng-deep not applying style to material checkbox

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to do a simple checkbox background color change for a material multiselect.

I've tried doing both

`.mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked { background-color: #a9a9a9 !important; }`

and

`:host ::ng-deep .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked { background-color: #a9a9a9 !important; }`

in the component.css but neither of them work, and I don't want to leave it as just

`::ng-deep .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked { background-color: #a9a9a9 !important; }`

since it would bleed out into other components, meaning ViewEncapsulation.None and doing it in the main styles.css file are out of the question. Thank you for your assistance.

EDIT: I've also tried adding a class to the `<mat-select>` itself and then doing `mat-select.class .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked { background-color: #a9a9a9 !important: }` into the styles.css but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Try to add class on the checkbox, then you can do: class ::ng-deep selector.

Comment: I'm unaware of how I can add a class to the checkbox itself since it's a part of the built in `<mat-select><mat-option>{{option}}</mat-option></mat-select>` html that comes with mat-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the class to `panelClass` attribute, please find below the changes!

[Material Select API Reference](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelect)

css

```
.custom-checkbox-color .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked {
  background-color: #a9a9a9 !important;
}
```

html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select
    [formControl]="toppings"
    multiple
    panelClass="custom-checkbox-color"
  >
    @for (topping of toppingList; track topping) {
    <mat-option [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
    }
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/9nbt6j?file=src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fexample%2Fselect-multiple-example.html)

Comment: It worked but I had to add ::ng-deep, but since it's subselected in css it should be fine, right?

Comment: @Baltr ng-deep is not so great, this is the best solution since it won't trigger build warnings!

Comment: I know, that's why I try to avoid it as much as possible or use `:host ::ng-deep` if I need to

Comment: Is there a way to use it on a `<input matInput>` with a `<mat-autocomplete>`? I've tried doing a similar thing by putting the panelClass on both, and tried putting it on the `<mat-form-field>` wrapper they have, but it doesn't work

Comment: Well, I found that panelClass works on <mat-autocomplete> but I needed to also add the same class to the autocomplete otherwise it wouldn't apply

Comment: @Baltr just add the class and it will work, it's like that to prevent affecting other component

Comment: Thank you for all your help @Naren Murali, just saved me a bunch of trouble now and in the future! I understand all this a bit better now!

Comment: ::ng-deep is deprecated and shouldn't be used, but there is many cases where you have no other choice. In that case it's a good practice to wrap mat element with a class and call that class before ng-deep, so it won't affect other elements. You don't need:root before ng deep and you can call any class before as long as mat element is it's child.